# Insert date into a grid field if empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, processmaker

3rd party web based workflow application. Trying to get javascript to insert todays date into a grid date field if the field is empty.

If I set the following code:

```
function todayDate(){

  var today = new Date();
  var dd = today.getDate();
  var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
  var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

  if (dd<10) { 
    dd='0'+dd
  } 

  if (mm<10) {
    mm='0'+mm
  } 

  today = yyyy+'/'+mm+'/'+dd;
  $("#Travel_ItineraryDetails").setValue(today,1,1);
}
todayDate();
```

it inserts the date into the correct field. This also overwrites the date each time the user opens the form.

Grid name: Travel_ItineraryDetails

Field name: date

Field is the first field in the grid hence teh 1,1 in the .setValue command above.

Comment: how does that check for the field named 'date' in the grid called 'Travel_ItineraryDetails'?

Comment: So what's the issue? What do you expect? What do you get?

Comment: I need an if statement that will check if the field is empty and insert the date set out in the function however i'm having trouble as it is in a grid. I'm not sure how to get the if statement to look in a grid.

Answer (score 0):

in grid one moment..

and with `processmaker` ..
use `$("#gridId").getValue(row, col)`
(Available Version: 3.0.1.3 and later. )

[Documentation here](http://wiki.processmaker.com/3.0/JavaScript_Functions_and_Methods#grid.getValue)

---

variant without `processmaker`

```js
function todayDate(){

  var today = new Date();
  var dd = today.getDate();
  var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
  var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

  if (dd<10) { 
    dd='0'+dd
  } 

  if (mm<10) {
    mm='0'+mm
  } 

  today = yyyy+'/'+mm+'/'+dd;
  var elem = document.getElementById("Travel_ItineraryDetails");
  
if( elem.innerHTML =="")  
//  $("#Travel_ItineraryDetails").html(today); with jQuery
elem.innerHTML = today;
}
todayDate();
```

```html
<div id=Travel_ItineraryDetails></div>
```

```js
function todayDate(){

  var today = new Date();
  var dd = today.getDate();
  var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
  var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

  if (dd<10) { 
    dd='0'+dd
  } 

  if (mm<10) {
    mm='0'+mm
  } 

  today = yyyy+'/'+mm+'/'+dd;
  var elem = document.getElementById("Travel_ItineraryDetails").rows[0].cells[0];
  
if( elem.innerHTML =="")  
//  $("#Travel_ItineraryDetails").html(today); with jQuery
elem.innerHTML = today;
}
todayDate();
```

```html
<table id="Travel_ItineraryDetails">
    <tr class="row">
        <td class="cell"></td>
        <td class="cell">2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row">
        <td class="cell">3</td>
        <td class="cell">4</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do that in ProcessMaker, One is by using Trigger and another is by writing Javascript.

The answer by Akubik is good but if you want trigger, you just need to use it in PHP code like this:

```
$date_field = @@date_field;
//it is my hobby to store processmaker variables in a PHP variables
if(!empty($date_field))
{
   @@date_field =  date("Y/m/d"); 
   //i force PM variable to use the date for today
  //by default processmaker is using YYYY-MM-DD
}
```

Place this in a trigger and put that trigger Before Dynaform.